# Laravel get форма

Tags: php, laravel, search

Всем привет, тут такая штука => я делаю сайт на Laravel, а сейчас именно страницу поиска

это get который отслеживает страницу поиска

```
Route::get('/search/{query}/',
    'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@search_page'
)->name('search');
```

это функция которая осуществляет поиск

```
public function search_page(string $query) {
        $search = new article();
        return view('search', [
            'data' => $search->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->simplePaginate(6),
            'search_query' => $query
        ]);
    }
```

здесь все ок

поиск работает когда я перехожу на [http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/Содержимое_поиска/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0/)

но как мне сделать форму с get запросом на эту страницу, я знаю только как делать post формы в Laravel?!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче говоря я переделал так =>

```
public function search_page(Request $req) {

        $validation = $req->validate([
            'query' => 'required|min:3|max:100'
        ]);

        $query = $req->input('query');
        $search = new article();
        return view('search', [
            'data' => $search->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->simplePaginate(6),
            'search_query' => $query
        ]);
    }



Route::get('/search',
    'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@search_page'
)->name('search');
```

и такая пагин...  `{{ $data->appends(['query' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::input('query')])->links() }}`

Answer (score 0):

http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?field1=avada&field2=kedavra

**routes:**

```
Route::get('/search', [ArticleController::class, 'searchPage'])->name('searchPage');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function searchPage(Request $request) 
{    
    $request->get('field1') // avada  
    $request->get('field2') // kedavra
    ...
```